# Kendo Grid JSP Tag Paging Buttons Not Paging

Tags: jsp, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

(Please don't judge me, I'm supporting a legacy application).

I am trying to make a kendo-ui grid work via JSP. The data loads, but I can't page.

First, here's the JSP:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix="kendo" uri="http://www.kendoui.com/jsp/tags"%>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Astro Search (Gliese Only)</title>
        <link href="resources/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="resources/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="resources/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="resources/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <script src="resources/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="resources/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
        <script src="resources/js/kendo.dataviz.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Astro Query (Gliese Only)</h1>
        <kendo:grid name="catalogGrid" pageable="true">
            <kendo:grid-columns>
                <kendo:grid-column title="Name" field="name"></kendo:grid-column>
                <kendo:grid-column title="Component" field="component"></kendo:grid-column>
                <kendo:grid-column title="Right Ascension" field="ra"></kendo:grid-column>
                <kendo:grid-column title="Declination" field="dec"></kendo:grid-column>
                <kendo:grid-column title="Spectral Type" field="spectralTypeFull"></kendo:grid-column>
                <kendo:grid-column title="Visual Magnitude" field="visualMagnitude"></kendo:grid-column>
                <kendo:grid-column title="Absolute Magnitude" field="absoluteMagnitude"></kendo:grid-column>
                <kendo:grid-column title="Parallax" field="parallax"></kendo:grid-column>
                <kendo:grid-column title="HD Number" field="hd"></kendo:grid-column>
            </kendo:grid-columns>
            <kendo:dataSource pageSize="25" serverPaging="true" data="data">
                <kendo:dataSource-transport read="/gliese/query">
                </kendo:dataSource-transport>
                <kendo:dataSource-schema data="data" total="total"></kendo:dataSource-schema>
            </kendo:dataSource>
            <kendo:grid-pageable input="true" numeric="false" />
        </kendo:grid>


    </body>
</html>
```

The backend is much less primitive, being a Spring MVC controller calling a Spring Data JPA repository:

```java
    @GetMapping(value="/gliese/query")
    public @ResponseBody
    DataSourceResult<Gliese> query(@RequestParam Integer take, @RequestParam Integer skip,
                           @RequestParam Integer page, @RequestParam Integer pageSize) {

        // query for result
        return new DataSourceResult<Gliese>(count, take.longValue(), result.getContent());
    }
```

The `DataSourceResult` is defined as below:

```java
public class DataSourceResult<T> implements Serializable {

    private Long total;
    private Long pageSize;
    private List<T> data;

    public DataSourceResult() {
    }

    public DataSourceResult(Long total, Long pageSize, List<T> data) {
        this.total = total;
        this.pageSize = pageSize;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Long getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(Long total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    public Long getPageSize() {
        return pageSize;
    }

    public void setPageSize(Long pageSize) {
        this.pageSize = pageSize;
    }

    public List<T> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<T> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

As mentioned, the data loads fine on initial page load, but the paging buttons do NOT attempt to load the next data.

Below is what I am seeing at the bottom of my grid:

[image: page controls]

Can anyone help?

Comment: I believe KendoUI sends the paging information as query parameters. Does the query string bind to your `@RequestParam`? Also, your `query` method, it seems `page` and `pageSize` aren't used in `new DataSourceResult`, so how can it do paging?

Comment: It doesn't do anything, including attempt to contact the server for the next page.

Comment: First things first. You have to make sure back end is receiving the information sent from the front end. Breakdown the big problem into smaller ones.

Comment: Though this is KendoUI jQuery, this could be helpful. My answer talks about `page`, `pageSize`, `skip`, and `take` which is server side paging.